# Google Sheets/Form Not Updating Properly

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google form that I am using to collect a rather large amount of data. The form responses are going to a Google sheet. From that Google sheet I am running several queries and using importrange to move the data to other sheets.

Recently I have had an issue where the data is being submitted successfully on the form, but the data does not show up on the Google sheet. I do have a script that is running on form submitision (on the sheet and not the form) and I do see the script is running. I can also view the individual responses on the Google form itself, but they will not go to the Google sheet.

I have discovered that if I unlink and relink the sheet the new data will appear but further form submissions will not appear unless I repeat this. I have also tried sendig the responses to a different workbook and the form submissions come through fine. This issue appears related to the sheet specifically and not the form as the form is working fine.

I did do some research and noticed a thread where a lot of people have this exact issue but no resolution was ever provided.

I will also mention that I had this issue before but it seemed to resolve itself within about an hour. This time it is lasting for several hours and it is not resolving itself.

Answer (score 1):

try forcing it:

```
=IF(NOW()=NOW(); QUERY(...); )
```

and check the settings:

[image]